# Storing toggle button states in Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I want there to be ~100 toggle buttons with a hardcoded item associated with them (All users will have the same items) - The toggle represents whether the user has the item or not, in my SwiftUI app. I'm using Firebase for the backend and have implemented authentication and a database (realtime but I think I'm going to change to firestore).

How would I optimally store whether these buttons are checked / unchecked for each user that uses the app?

A solution could be to have all 100 items stored under the users id in a database but this leads to ALOT of repeated data. (1000 users would mean that 100,000 item states are being stored for only 100 distinct items). (Not great for scalability)

E.g :

```
{
  "users": {
    "1": {
      "name": "Donald Biden",
      "items" : {
      "House" : "False",
      "Car" : "True",
       .
       .
      },
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "Joe Trump",
      "items" : {
      "House" : "True",
      "Car" : "True",
    },
    "3": { ... }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is also the first approach I would think of.

To improve it: Since a toggle button has only two states, you could only store all true values OR all false ones, whatever you think would lead to less entries.

Example if you store only true: in your app you could check if there's a true value for a specific button for the user, otherwise just set it to false.

Edit: to make it more clear, you would not store `"House" : "False"` in my example. Because there's no House value then you would just set the button to false.

Comment: Thanks @tschoninas I did consider that also but was confused as to where I would retrieve the items that user doesn't have. Would you create all items in the app and then initialise the values on launch?

Comment: I think I do not completely understand what you mean with "retrieve the items that user doesn't have". If the key (e.g. "house") is not included in your database, then the user does not have the item.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends how you structured your database. However, if you structure it this way, that might help you to use less data storage:

A table matching returning all keys with their unique ids:

```
KeysTable:

1: "House",
2: "Car",
...
```

Then, each user's item list could look like this:

```
"Items": [1, 4, 5, 6, 8, ...] // List only the key ids with "true" values
```

Lastly, each user can use the keys table to retrieve which keys are on and which ones are off:

```
Pseudocode:

OnItems = user.items.map { KeysTable.getValueWithKey[$0] }
OffItems = KeysTable.keys.difference(user.items).map { KeysTable.getValueWithKey[$0] }
```